# (Un)countable set of regular language.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, computer-science

Suppose alphabet **Σ={d,e,l,t}** and **A** is the **set** of all **languages** "produced" by Σ, which all of them have the property **not** to **include** the string **"delete"**. The question is: **Is** set **A** **countable**? 
I have tried using the Diagonal Argument but it does not work. Any suggestions to a "better" approach?

Answer (score 3):

It is not countable since it is equal to the set of subsets of the set $\Sigma^* - \{delete\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\Sigma_- := \{d,e,l\}$. Then no language over $\Sigma_-$ contains the string "delete" and any language over $\Sigma_-$ is also a language over $\Sigma$. Since the set of all languages over $\Sigma_-$ is uncountable, the claim follows.

Comment: The set of all regular languages over a finite alphabet *is* countable. The set of all languages over a nonempty alphabet is not.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Thanks for spotting my mistake.